# Term::ReadLine: return values of readline

Tags: perl, encoding, terminal, console, readline

To get the right output in the following script I have to decode the value returned by `readline`.

Is it safe to assume that decoding the return-value of `readline` is required for all [Term::ReadLine](https://metacpan.org/release/Term-ReadLine) backends?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;

use Encode;
use Encode::Locale;
use Term::ReadLine;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(console_out)';

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new( 'readline' );
say $term->ReadLine;    # Term::ReadLine::Gnu
my $line = $term->readline( ':' );

say decode( 'console_in', $line );
```